# Send bootstrap class when you have a validation error to an input component in laravel 8

Tags: php, validation, components, laravel-8

How can I send a Bootstrap class to an `input` component of laravel 8, if I have an error in field validation. The validation error is displayed but it is not sent to the `input` component.

My componente laravel:

```
@props(['disabled' => false])

<input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-control']) !!}>
```

My form.

```
<x-input 
    id="avatar" 
    type="file" 
    name="avatar" 
    aria-describedby="avatarFeedback"
    class="@error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror"
/>

@error('avatar')
<div id="avatarFeedback" class="invalid-feedback">
    {{ $message }}
</div>
@enderror
```

When the validations are run.

In the browser it just shows me `<input class="form-control @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror"/>`.

But it should show `<input class="form-control is-invalid"/>`